# How to set the content height to fill?

Tags: html, css

From this code: [JSFiddle_original](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/LUy3W/9/)

I would like to set the wrapper height to the lorem ipsum text height.

So I created this code: [JSFiddle_mine](http://jsfiddle.net/LUy3W/51/)
But the wrapper height is always the same as the html height. How to se the wrapper size to the text height?

```
.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I did this but now the wrapper size is the same as the html-body size.

Comment: how about removing `height:100%` and let the wrapper take `auto` height according to it's content..?

Comment: its not working, the blur effect not appear after that modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you need to remove `.wrapper { height: 100%; }`, so that the height is decided by its content.

Then it should work if you change `.content` to `position: relative`. Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow, so they can't influence the size of their parent.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/W7Wap/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the relative positioning and the height: 100% from the ".wrapper". Remove the absolute positioning from the ".content". There seems to be too many needless positioning tricks in the CSS.

Comment: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nJz4A/)

Comment: i tried what you wrote but not working.. could you create it in my fiddle?

Comment: Thanks thykka! but its not working because i need a blur effect behind the content div. This blur div is the .blur class..